# Model is empty for delete SPARQL query

Tags: sparql, apache-jena

I'm using the following SPARQL query
DELETE DATA {    } ;

After I executing the following lines,
 Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
 UpdateAction.parseExecute(sparqlUpdateQuery, model);

my model is still empty. I am trying to execute the query on unnamed graph. I'm new to Jena, please guide.

Comment: Without seeing data, more code and query, it's impossible to give any helpful answer. For Jena, there exists a very good documentation, also with tutorials.

Comment: And if you DELETE something from an empty Jena model, what do you expect instead of an empty model as result?